# Alpha Testing - "This app is incompatible with your device"

Tags: android

I'm trying to test the licencing on an app:

1. Uploaded the apk as an alpha to google play in the dev console
2. added tester emails
3. visited the testers' link once it was published and live
4. **Problem**: It says my device is incompatible with the app!

I debugged directly from Android Studio via usb on the same device, and when I upload the apk to my phone, I can install it directly.

Also, Google Play gives me no hints as to what the issue of obstruction is. How do I debug this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, keep an eye on the details: I had the noob error of using `maxSdkVersion` instead of the proper `minSdkVersion` - an oversight of 2 characters.